# Pass a value to another controller which executes first

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers headerController, aboutController.

headerController -> To maintain the navigation and redirection

aboutController -> works when about-us page loads.

My issue is I have to update the headerController variable value when aboutController loads. i.e When about us page loads, the navigation about-us should active, similar to all the pages.

This is my code:

```
app.service('shareService', function () {
    var data;
    return {
        getProperty: function () {
            return data;
        },
        setProperty: function (value) {
            data = value;
        }
    };
});
app.controller('headerController', function ($scope, shareService) {
    $scope.navigation = [
        {url: '#!/home', name: 'Home'},
        {url: '#!/about-us', name: 'About Us'},
        {url: '#!/services', name: 'Services'}
    ];
    var data = shareService.getProperty();
    console.log(data);
    $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
    $scope.itemClicked = function ($index) {
        console.log($index);
        $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
    };
});
app.controller('aboutController', function ($scope, shareService) {
    console.log('test');
    $scope.selectedIndex = 1;
    shareService.setProperty({navigation: $scope.selectedIndex});
});
```

**header.html:**

```
<header ng-controller="headerController">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="first-half col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#!/home"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-half col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="social-share">
                    <ul id="social-share-header">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul ng-repeat="nav in navigation">
                <li class="main-nav" ng-class="{ 'active': $index == selectedIndex }"
             ng-click="itemClicked($index)">
                    <a href="{{nav.url}}">{{nav.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**index.html**
This is how my template works.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <section class="first-section">
            <div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="second-section">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </section>
        <section class="last-section">
            <div ng-include="'views/footer.html'"></div>
        </section>
    </body>
```

Update 1: Added index.html file.

Update 2: Issue explanation: If I run directly to the about us page, then still the home navigation is on active. But it should be About us

Comment: You can set a variable inside a service that will be updated by `AboutController` and read by `HeaderController`

Comment: I still can't see what the problem is. I suppose header controller exists for the header which is a separate template which is included in the DOM all the time. So when the user clicks a nav element from the header then the itemClicked is triggered. Same happens even when about controller is manipulated, header controller is still there. Could you specify the problem please ?

Comment: PLease check my updates

Answer (score 0):

What is you are looking for is event based communication between your controllers. This can be easily done using. $rootScope.$on, $rootScope.$emit and $rootScope.$broadcast. Since explaining all three of them in this answer will be overkill. Kindly go through this [article](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angularjs/understanding-emit-broadcast-and-on-in-angularjs)